# yarn create react-app my-app и имя пользователя в папке 'C:\Users' с пробелом

Tags: windows, yarn

Ребят привет, проблема следующая. Я пользователь Windows, и моя папка пользователя 'C:\Users\IGOR FILIN' написана с пробелом в имени, из за этого я полагаю у меня конфликт с установкой проекта с yarn через консоль. У кого было подобное и как разобраться не меняя через администратора имя пользователя, ибо может полететь вся система.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46871452/spaces-in-path-npm/46871748#46871748) является решением?

Comment: @igor к сожалению там говориться про npm, npm у меня работает, что странно, а вот yarn не хочет

Comment: Попробуй сделать симлинк через `mklink`. И указывать уже путь без пробела.

Answer (score 0):

Проблемный путь используется в качестве примера: C:\Users\Espen Jacobsson

Предпринятые шаги:

Закройте любую запущенную оболочку Запустите cmd в административном режиме (mklink - это функция cmd, и не будет работать в PowerShell) Создайте перекресток каталогов (жесткую ссылку на каталог) с помощью команды mklink:

```
mklink /J "C:\Users\EspenJacobsson" "C:\Users\Espen Jacobsson"
```

Выполните команды:

```
yarn cache dir
yarn global bin
```

Обратите внимание на выходные данные, как указано в комментарии выше, они будут выглядеть примерно так:

C:\Users\Espen Jacobsson\AppData\Local\Yarn\Cache\v6
C:\Users\Espen Jacobsson\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin

Выполните команды:

`yarn config set cache-folder "C:\Users\EspenJacobsson\AppData\Local\Yarn\Cache"` (без V6)
`yarn config set prefix "C:\Users\EspenJacobsson\AppData\Local\Yarn"` (без bin)
Перезагрузите оболочку и проверьте, что новые пути установлены с помощью команд yarn cache dir и yarn global bin.

Если пути правильно изменены, yarn create должен теперь работать.

Надеюсь, это кому-нибудь поможет

Comment: Переведите пожалуйста ответ на русский язык.